# PHP CURL condition with httpcode reponse

Tags: php, curl

i am trying to add an condition on my PHP CURL code ,to continue executing curl until i get httpcode = 200 when get bad gateway response because the website have a high traffic , thene if get httpcode 200 do some instruction .

so i am trying with my  code but it'ss not helpful .

```
    <?php

    $ch = curl_init("https://example.com/index.php");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '151.80.143.155:53281');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'C:\AppServ\www\cloud\cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.53 Safari/537.36');
    curl_exec($ch);

    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        while(true){
            if($http !== 200){
                curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            sleep(8);
            }

            else{
            // Do some instruction ...
        sleep(8);
        }
        }

    curl_close($ch);


?>
```

Please guys how can i do this condition ?

thank you guys .

Comment: You could pull the headers and look at the `0` index for the status code. http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php

Comment: where is `$http` defined?

Comment: so if i get this right, when the server is too busy you are making it more busy by firing another request ... bad idea.  Also, what would you do if you get a 301, 302, 401, etc ... if you were to hit twice on my sites and get a 401, your next hit wont even get a connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just named a variable wrongly. You're checking `$http` while you should be checking `$httpcode`

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init("https://example.com/index.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '151.80.143.155:53281');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'C:\AppServ\www\cloud\cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.53 Safari/537.36');
curl_exec($ch);

$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
while(true){
    if($httpcode !== 200){ // This line was wrong
        curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        sleep(8);
    } else{
        // Do some instruction ...
        sleep(8);
        break;
    }
}

curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Comment: I would also add a maximum number of iterations, you don't want to keep trying the same download for the next 5 years...

Comment: Thank you :-) , please how can i stop while loop  when $httpcode is 200  and do some instruction OUTSIDE the loop .

Comment: With a ```break```. I updated the code to show this. After you break the code exits the while and you can keep adding code.

Comment: Thank you So match  :)  ,  So if gateway it will be executed until got 200 ? thene Break to go outside  LOOP ?